# DC 12680 charging

Tags: battery-charging

Recently discovered one of these 12v packs (model DC 12680) sitting in a box for at least 5 years. A meter says its still putting out 12.xx v, so hopefully this means the cells are still good. Looks like this:
[image: DC 12680 battery pack]

I'm not 100% on how to charge this though. Looking it up, these packs seem to always be sold with an adapter included, but can't quite tell if this is some specific +12v CC/CV adapter (like a +4.2v li-on charger), or if such a thing even exists...

After some digging, I can only find one picture that shows an adapter  that I can just barely make out the writing and just says 12v @ 500ma + center pin positive: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61GaMwwE8GL.jpg

The input on the battery pack itself says 12.6v dc, so I'm thinking I can use any 12v adapter? (and I have a few that are 24W) Just wanted to be sure before I actually try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't charge a battery especially a lithium battery without some form of current and voltage limits.

Connecting a power supply directly to a lithium battery is a recipe for a fire or   battery destruction.
At the very minimum a battery charger needs to control and limit the current flowing in to the battery and limit the max voltage to closely match the battery maximum voltage.

If you really want to use this pack buying specific adapter/charger for it may be best if you are not experienced with how charger controllers work. Some useful information [here](https://www.victronenergy.com/media/pg/Lithium_Battery_Smart/en/battery-charging-and-discharging.html) if you do want to learn more.

Comment: Hm, I did later find a tear down that showed each cell had its own over/under-charge protection and one comment under that tear down that mentioned there no cell balancing/charge controller/circuitry.... so it's probably better to try look for its original adapter.